# Matrix Multiplication with DataFrames (Julia)

Tags: dataframe, julia, linear-algebra

In Pandas there's a pretty neat operation for DataFrame matrix multiplication.

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2], "y":[2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrmae({"y":[2,3], "x":[1,2]})
```

Note that the columns are in a different order but when we do

```
df3 = df @ df2.T
```

df3 will come out looking like

```
     x    y
-----------
x | 5     8
y | 8    13
```

This is a bit fancier than converting df and df2 into matrices and multiplying them because:

1. The net result is a data frame and its indices and columns are labeled appropriately
2. No manipulation of matrices required to line up the columns properly.

Is there something comparable with DataFrames in Julia?

Comment: No - there is no such functionality. In general for this kind of operation I think you should rather use e.g. AxisArrays.jl not DataFrames.jl.

Comment: You can always do `DataFrame(Matrix(df1) * Matrix(df2), names(df2))`.

Comment: Running this on Python 3.7.4 I get labels of '0' and '1 on df3, not 'x' and 'y'.